# Ionic- Angular Js - Store array locally

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, ionic-framework

Hello I am developing an Ionic app and I have an array that I want to push items on to it, but not lose the data when I change screens. Also, I do not want to use a database. Is there any other way? to add to an existing array and store that array locally?

```
 $scope.tasksCollection = [
    { info: 'Go studying', measured: 'no', total: 1, done: 1, id: 1 },
    { info: 'Go to the beach', measured: 'no', total: 1, done: 1, id: 2},
    { info: 'Run', measured: 'yes', total: 30, done: 15, id: 3}
    ];

 $scope.tasksCollection.push({
        info: $scope.taskInfo,
        measured: $scope.result,
        total: total,
        done: 0,
        id: $scope.tasksCollection.length
    })
```

The add function is working perfectly I just loose the data when changing states.

Comment: yes, use service. it will be singleton and thus having the same content wherever you inject it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ionic local storage vs using service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28846266/ionic-local-storage-vs-using-service)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep data between controllers either use a service or local storage if you want to keep the data even when you quit the app.

### Service example

Further angular documentation regarding services: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

service.js:

```
angular.module('yourmodule.services')
    .service('Tasks', [function () {
        var collection = {
            tasks: []
        };

        return {
            getTasks : function(){ return collection.tasks; }
        }
    }]
);
```

controller.js

```
angular.module('yourmodule.controllers')
    .controller('TaskCtrl', ['$scope', 'Tasks',
        function($scope, Tasks){

   $scope.Tasks = Tasks //Expose service to template

   $scope.addTask = function(){
      Tasks.getTasks().push({name : 'a new task'});
   }
}]);
```

### Local storage example

This is an excellent library which provides easy localstorage access for angularjs: https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

```
angular.module('yourmodule.controllers')
        .controller('TaskCtrl', ['$scope', 'localStorageService',
            function($scope, localStorageService){

   $scope.collection = {
       tasks : localStorageService.get('tasks') || [];
   }

   $scope.addTask = function(){
      $scope.collection.tasks.push({name : 'a new task'});
      localStorageService.set('tasks', $scope.collection.tasks);
   }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about HTML5's locaStorage?

See Ionic formulas on [Using Local Storage](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/localstorage/).