# Better way of passing data between pages: HTML5 storage vs Angular service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am trying to pass data between two pages which are having Angular controllers.

Now I came across 2 different ways to pass data:

> 1. via Angular service (similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20181543/3098658))
> 2. using HTML5 storage option (either Local/Session [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage))

From development perspective I wanted to know as which is more preferred method of passing data? Can this scenario change if we are dealing with large JSON data ?

Comment: each strategy is viable, with pros and cons to both.  In general, you use a service when you are using the data within the current usage session of the app, and storage when you need to save data for use in future sessions.

Answer (score 0):

This answer - [Ionic local storage vs using service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28846266/ionic-local-storage-vs-using-service) - gives a good summary of the differences: local storage should be used primarily for data that will be used across a number of sessions or persists for a long time, whereas data in an Angular service is tied to that page.

Comment: The answer I linked to refers to Ionic local storage - refer to this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage one for details about HTML5 local stores. Same principle.